# mod_rewrite stopped working after server move

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess file

```
## Turn on RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

## Ignore
RewriteRule     (slir)  -   [L,NC]
RewriteRule     ^slir - [L,NC]

## CakePHP
RewriteRule     ^$      app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule     (.*)    app/webroot/$1  [L]
```

This used to work fine on my old host, but since moving to HostGator, the two rules under #ignore have stopped working. There is only two becaus ei am trying different things.

Basically all requests get sent to app/webroot but i have a folder called "slir" that I want to be excluded from this.

How can the second two rules work but the first two have stopped working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was because the htaccess file inside /slir/ had this:

```
# Prevent other scripts from interfering with SLIR
php_value auto_prepend_file none
php_value auto_append_file none
```

After commenting the two lines, the problem was gone

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rewrite flag [skip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s). If we find a match, then skip the rewrite rule following:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

# If we have a match for slir anywhere in the REQUEST_URI
# (case insensitive based on NC in supplied code)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [sS][Ll][Ii][Rr]
# then skip 1 rule.
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
#Match 0 or any character + and rewrite the URL.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have replace my code with yours and it still behaves the same.

Comment: Are these all of the rules in the `.htaccess` file? Also is `/slir/` a real directory?

Comment: Yes, i replaced the whole file with what you posted.

Comment: Is /slir/ a real directory?

Comment: Also do you have any rewrite rules in the vhost?

Comment: I am on shared hosting, so dont think ihave access to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Send all requests that do not start with `/slir` to the webroot.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/slir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [L]
```